# How can we Use getNearest function after the filter in RethinkDb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, rethinkdb

I have a  question  relating to rethinkdb  .  I am  querying for  getting nearest location  around  a  specific  point   and  its  going  fine   but  the problem is that   want to  filter the result   first   then apply  getNearest     but   getNearest  works  with table
can  anyone guide me here

here is the code   and it  works  fine  .   but  i want  the  filtered  result  first  then use GetNearest Location.

```
var point = r.point(73.07328600000005,33.633473);
 r.db('DB').table('infoCenter').getNearest(point,
   {index: 'location', unit: 'km', maxDist:1, maxResults: 2000}
   )
 .filter(function(kk) {
   return  kk('doc')('Deleted').default(false).eq(false)

   })
```

The Above code works  fine  But   what i  want  to  do is   to  filter  the  result  first  and  then use   getNearest method .   and getNearest method works only with table  .

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

An indexed operation such as `getNearest` cannot be performed after a `filter`.

You could instead use a unindexed `orderBy` with `distance`, for example:

```
.orderBy(ic => ic('location').distance(point))
```

Or, if you want to keep `unit`, `maxDist` and `maxResults`, something like:

```
.merge(ic => {distance: ic('location').distance(point, {unit: 'km'})})
.filter(ic => ic('distance').lt(1))
.orderBy('distance')
.limit(2000)
```